# Microtype expansion gets disabled when fontsize is changed! (lualatex)

Tags: luatex, fontsize, expansion, microtype

It seems like microtype's expansion gets disabled when fontsize is changed from default fontsize. Here are two pieces of code, in the first one expansion does work, in the second one it does not (as if microtype was never given options stretch and shrink).

Works:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\definecolor{textblack}{RGB}{26,25,25}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[expansion=true,stretch=500,shrink=500]{microtype}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Renderer=Basic]{Warnock Pro}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
    \color{textblack}
    \fontsize{9pt}{12pt}\selectfont
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \blindtext[10]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Command:

```sh
>> lualatex main.tex
```

Output:
[image: expansion works]

Doesn't work:

```
%main.tex
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\definecolor{textblack}{RGB}{26,25,25}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[expansion=true,stretch=500,shrink=500]{microtype}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Renderer=Basic]{Warnock Pro}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
    \color{textblack}
    \fontsize{8.8pt}{12pt}\selectfont
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \blindtext[10]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Command:

```sh
>> lualatex main.tex
```

Output:
[image: expansion does not work]
Please suggest if, and how can this be fixed, or if there is a problem with my code.

Thanks,

Aman

Comment: Does this problem occur with other fonts as well, or just with `Warnock Pro`? I'm afraid I can't answer this question as my system doesn't feature this font.

Comment: It occurs with other fonts as well. I tried it with two other fonts, including https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto (available for download for free), all have same problem.

Comment: looks as if microtype doesn't like a decimal fontsize.

Comment: After @UlrikeFischer's answer I researched if it is true that microtype doesn't like decimal fontsize in any condition, and turns out that is not the case. As we both know now, microtype applies its features only to a subset of fonts which it calls  named `font set`; check section 4 of microtype's manual. Table captioned "Predefined font sets" in the manual has some predefined font sets. From `microtype.sty`, I found that if one does not specify a subset of fonts to apply microtype's features to, then microtype defaults to its predefined subset named `basictext` (continued below).

Comment: Font set `basictext` specifies a list of font sizes to apply microtype's options; that list is `\normalsize, \footnotesize, \small, \large`. As `basictext` is the default fontset of microtype, this means microtype won't apply its magic to other font sizes. Microtype also comes with other predefined font sets that are less restrictive, for instance font set `all` has no restriction at all (meaning microtype's magic will be applied to all fonts, irrespective of their size, or encoding). Please check microtype manual's table captioned "Predefined font sets" for more information.

Comment: Just FYI, the `basictext` default set actually stems from the beginnings of the microtype package, when pdftex's font expansion mechanism required to embed all expanded font instances in the pdf file. This has long changed, so I guess it's time for microtype to adapt to modern times, too, and to make the `alltext` set the default.

Comment: @Robert, why not use font set "all" instead of "alltext"? I had asked that question in my first comment to Ulrike Fischer's answer. Am curious what is the difference between them, and when one makes sense over other.

Comment: It's a trade-off between quality vs. time/memory. 1) The time factor actually seems pretty insignificant (eg., compiling microtype.dtx with `alltext` takes 9.5 secs., with `all` 9.6 secs.). 2) Concerning memory however it is not impossible that one might hit a hard border when loading a great number of fonts. / On the other hand, it may even be undesirable to have math fonts or tt fonts distorted. This said, I think I'll go with the default `alltext-nott`. But of course, that's just the default, meant to meet the demands of most users, and nothing should prevent you from using `all` instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

microtype sets up the font expansion only for a restricted set of font size. If you add you size to the list it works (redefining basictext is probably not the best way to do it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\definecolor{textblack}{RGB}{26,25,25}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[expansion=true,stretch=500,shrink=500]{microtype}
\DeclareMicrotypeSet*{basictext}
{ encoding = {OT1,T1,T2A,LY1,OT4,QX,T5,EU1,EU2,TU},
 family = {rm*,sf*},
 series = {md*},
 size = {normalsize,footnotesize,small,large,9.1} %added 9.1
}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
\begin{document}
    \fontsize{9.1pt}{12pt}\selectfont
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \blindtext[10]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

You can lift the restriction also by e.g. using another set than the default:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\definecolor{textblack}{RGB}{26,25,25}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[expansion=true,stretch=500,shrink=500]{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[expansion]{alltext}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
\begin{document}
    \fontsize{9.1pt}{12pt}\selectfont
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \blindtext[10]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

OR even more terse, by passing `expansion=alltext` as a package option while loading microtype:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\definecolor{textblack}{RGB}{26,25,25}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[expansion=alltext,stretch=500,shrink=500]{microtype}% expansion=all would also work as that set too does not have restrictions on size, and is the least restrictive of all predefined sets
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}
\begin{document}
    \fontsize{9.1pt}{12pt}\selectfont
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \blindtext[10]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

To be frank, I don't know why people use `microtype` at all.  Granted, it has some nice interfaces like `textls`, but for expansion I can achieve the same things with two lines of Lua and a font feature.  This also does not have the font size problem.

```latex
%main.tex
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\definecolor{textblack}{RGB}{26,25,25}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[expansion=false]{microtype}
\directlua{
  fonts.expansions.setups.default.stretch = 500
  fonts.expansions.setups.default.shrink = 500
}
\adjustspacing=2
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Renderer=Basic,RawFeature={expansion=default}]{Roboto}
\sloppy
\begin{document}
    \color{textblack}
    \fontsize{8.8pt}{12pt}\selectfont
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \blindtext[10]
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Explanation of commands used:

1. `\adjustspacing`: From luatex manual: "When `\adjustspacing` has value 2, hz optimization will be applied to glyphs and kerns. Whenthe value is 3, only glyphs will be treated. A value smaller than 2 disables this feature." So `\adjustspacing=2` enables font expansion, equivalent of `microtype`'s `expansion=true` (which anyway is by default).
2. `\directlua{...stretch = 500, ...}`: lualatex equivalent for `microtype`'s package option `stretch=500`.
3. `\usepackage[expansion=false]{microtype}` Passing `expansion=false` ensures that you can still use microtype for its other features, while expansion is handled using lua. If you do not pass `expansion=false`, your lualatex run will fail with an error: "error: (font expansion): font has been expanded with different expansion step", and no pdf will be produced.

Comment: Thanks Henri, I confirm that this works. Though I found a bug in luatex manual or behavior. Just like for @Ulrike Fischer's answer, I tried enabling, and disabling font expansion. According to lualatex manual (latest at the time of this writing), passing a  value smaller than `2` to `\adjustspacing` should disable font expansion. I tried `\adjustspacing=1`, it seems to disable shrink, but not stretch. Then I tried value `\adjustspacing=0`, and that seems to disable both shrink and stretch. Can someone please confirm, and file a ticket on luatex?

Comment: @reportaman https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/096431.html Until this is fixed, just use `\adjustspacing=0` to turn it off.

Comment: Thanks Henri for confirming, and filing a ticket on luatex devs.

Comment: @reportaman Actually I think it is a documentation bug, because the behaviour of `\adjustspacing=1` is identical to `\pdfadjustspacing=1` of pdfTeX: “Font expansion can be activated in two modes. When `\pdfadjustspacing` is set to `1`, font expansion is
applied after TeX’s normal paragraph breaking routines have broken the paragraph into lines. In this case,
line breaks are identical to standard TeX behavior.”

Comment: Henri, yes, I was going to chime in in the same vein. You are right that it's a documentation bug, as Hans sort of acknowledged in [this lengthy discussion](https://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2017-July/006584.html), adding that they're omitting it by intention: "Level 1 is rather useless ... and by not mentioning it we hope that it will not be used (we might remove all traces some day)." (@reportaman)

Comment: Also, it seems to me that the glyph+kerns vs. only glyph expansion is wrong in luatex. The results with pdftex and luatex are the same for me with \pdfadjustspacing=2 and \adjustspacing=3, but not with a value of 2 for both, which is what I would have expected.

Comment: @Robert Pretty sure this is because of differences in font handling.